# How to get news from my website in my android application?

Tags: android

I have my own news website. Now I am making an android app version of it.

How do I pick up news from my website in my android app.

My website has a **tile based format of news**(with a picture and a headline over it).
Now I have made a front end version of it with *blank* picture tiles in my android app but how do I keep refreshing the news(picture+headlines) by picking the latest news from the website so that the tile changes automatically **every time I change the news in my website**.
I am new to android so a very specific answer with code would be appreciated.

Comment: Add a web service inbetween, and let both your website and mobile application use it.

Comment: First : Go through this [Getting Started with Parsing JSON in Android](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/).   Then, this [connecting with web Api and implementing it in php](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

As i've would have done it is:

You save the news items in your Database. Just connect your android app to your MySQL database and everytime someone opens the app call the Query of `SELECT * FROM` selected by last inserted or on date.

Goodluck.

Comment: It's not a good idea to connect the app directly to the database. Prefer using a Web backend that delivers JSON for example. Reason: Android apps can easily be decompiled, so someone might find out your database password.

Answer (score 0):

Create an api that the app user will connect (most common is php) to your server (ex. ursite.com\getNews.php). This server api will then perform the query to your news collections and return the news article(image url & news contents) back to the app.

Comment: and how do we do that ? I have no idea of php. Do I add php code in app or in the website coding ?

Comment: That would be on a remote server where your app will connect to.